# jqGrid cannot be applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid in my asp.net mvc4 project and in one of my view I have the following:

```
<table id="_componentGrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
</table>
<div id="_componentPager" style="text-align: center;">
</div>
```

and I have a javascript file that begins like this:

```
function showGrid() {
    $('#_componentGrid').jqGrid({
        caption: paramFromView.Caption,....
```

in runtime an error is generated:

```
The object does not accept the property or method 'jqGrid'.
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that jqGrid is not loaded. You should verify that `grid.locale-en.js` and `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` (or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`) will be loaded on the page *after* jQuery. It could be  in general conflicts between jqGrid and the *version* of jQuery which you use on the page. In any way I recommend you to open source of the page having error and verify the `<head>` part of it and all other places where `<script>` are used on the page. The order and the versions of loaded JavaSctripts frameworks and plugins can be important. I recommend you to compare the order of included files with the order from [My first grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid#html_file) example of jqGrid documentation.